# What is the Objective-C equivalent of 'weak self' in a Swift closure?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, closures, weak

Could you tell me the equivalent of:

```
var didTapURL: ((_ url: URL) -> Void)?

..........

myObject.didTapURL = { [weak self] (url) in
     self?.manageUrl(url)
}
```

in Objectice-C?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is `__weak`, see below

```
__weak __typeof(self) weakSelf = self;

// ...

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
      [weakSelf call_some_selector];
    });
```